# Tcl script breaks out of foreach loop

Tags: foreach, nested, tcl, expect

I have a tcl script to log into devices and print SUCCESS. This is the script:

The file: (the first IP is valid, and can be logged into, the next 3 are fake).

```
192.38.133.145
178.18.34.48
183.24.56.3
145.234.67.145
```

The script:

```
#!/bin/expect
package require Expect

set file [open "hosts" r]
set f_data [read $file]
set data [split $f_data "\n"]

foreach host $data {
set timeout 8
    if {$host > 0} {
                ## GETS THE HOST IP##
                set host_ip $host

                ##LOGS INTO THE DEVICE##
                spawn ssh test@$host_ip
                expect {
                        "password:" {
                                puts "SUCCESS"
                        } timeout {
                                puts "Could not connect to host: ${host_ip}"
                                #break
                        }

                }
        send "password\r"
        expect ">"
        send "en\r"
        }
}
```

If I do not include the break, I get the message could not connect to host, but instead of looping to the next host, it sends `"en\r"`. 
when I do include the `break`, it gives the message that it cannot reach the host (the second IP, which is expected) and the script ends there (it does not process the 3rd IP). How do I cannot seem to get it to process the 3rd and 4th IPs.
I used the method suggested by potrzebie in this thread: [TCL: loops How to get out of inner most loop to outside?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14410431/tcl-loops-how-to-get-out-of-inner-most-loop-to-outside)
and still cannot get it to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`break` should work. The `expect` man page has this to say in the documentation for the `expect` command:

> Actions such as `break` and `continue` cause control structures (i.e., `for`, `proc`) to behave in the usual way.

I'd write your loop like this:

```
foreach host $data {
    # very basic data validation: an ipv4 address contains some dots
    if {[string match {*.*.*.*} $host]} {
        spawn ssh test@$host
        expect {
            "password:" {
                puts "SUCCESS"
                send "password\r"
                exp_continue
            } 
            timeout {
                puts "Could not connect to host: $host"
                continue
            }
            ">" {
                # I see a prompt. Fall out of this "expect loop"
            }
        }
        send "en\r"
        expect ">"

        # do something to close the connection
        send "exit\r"
        expect eof
    }
}
```

Comment: It still does not consider the last 2 ip addresses. It logs into the first device. Then it spawns the ssh to the second device, it gives the message: `could not connect to host`, and then it ends. It does not spawn an ssh to the other 2 (last) IP addresses on the list.